# Switch between windows on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows when I do alt+tab I can switch between windows. If I have 5 firefox windows open then using alt+tab will switch between them.

On my MacBook, cmd+tab switches between applications, not windows, so it will switch between firefox and xcode, but not between two different firefox windows.

I am sure there is *some* way to use keyboard shortcuts to switch between active windows. What am I missing?

Comment: Just in case you never saw it: see also http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343 and http://www.apple.com/support/switch101/

Comment: @Arjan this mostly doesn't work on international keyboards, where often `\`` on same key as `´` and is obtained by pressing `Shift`+`´` :-(

Comment: @Nir Levy **THANKS!** On my german keyboard (OS X 10.8) the mappings were "Focus to next window" => `Cmd`+`\``, and "Focus to ?toolbar?(Seitenleiste des Fensters)" =>  `Cmd`+`Shift`+`\``. Since both `´` and `\`` are on same key (see my previous comment), rotating between application windows went only in one direction. All I had to to was change the 1st mapping to `Cmd`+`´` and 2nd mapping to something else, e.g. `Cmd`+`ß`, and suddenly window switching works in both directions: `Cmd`+`´` and `Cmd`+`Shift`+ `´`. That simple... BTW, the default suggested by OSX is `Cmd`+`<` for Window switching.

Comment: One of most annoying thing on MAC for programmers. Why are the making us use 2 shortcuts to switch between windows, so inefficient :/ Is there app which would let me group up my windows as I like?

Comment: An update from the future (as this question gets many views still): for users that prefer windows-type switching, you may wish to consider using an excellent little tool called HyperSwitch that does the job.

Comment: How do we change the system keyboard shortcuts? 
In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts there is nothing about changing window globally.
On the Italian keyboard the `~` character is hidden behind Alt-5 so not usable for this. 
I would like to change this in system. What command should I write if I create a new global shortcut?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> toggles
>   through the windows forward.
>
> <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>
>   toggles through the windows in
>   reverse.
>
> <kbd>Cmd</kbd> - <kbd>alt</kbd> -
>   arrowkey switches between tabs

Comment: What's that *angle bracket* shortcut again? It does not work on my mac. And why is it the only one using '+' instead of '-' between keys?

Comment: cmd-shift is nice, didn't know that before.

Comment: When did Cmd+> Cmd+< happen? I don't have them on 10.5.

Comment: On my Macbook Air with Mountain Lion, Cmd+> just beeps like an invalid key combination.  It does not switch windows.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - On my Macbook Air with Mountain Lion, Cmd+> just beeps like an invalid key combination. It does not switch windows.

Comment: What happens if my keyboard layout is different? I have the italian layout, and to get the ` symbol you need to press Alt + 9. Pressing Alt + Cmd + ` does not work. Is there anywhere where I could see the italian correspondant of this?

Comment: My macbook plus with mountain lion only beeps as @Howiecamp describes.

Comment: Doesn't work for Adium (

Comment: On my new MacBook Pro with Mavericks this just cycles within windows of the current application. It doesn't cycle all open windows of all open applications which is what alt-tab on Windows does.

Comment: @TomasAndrle, Cmd Shift arrow doesn't work on Sierra. (I tried with two finder windows.)

Comment: @Am1rr3zA, Where is the alt key?

Answer (score 14):

There's a 3rd party app called [Witch](http://www.manytricks.com/witch/) which will let you cycle through all windows of all apps.

Comment: Why in the world is there not an option in Mac OS to just enable this functionality over the default switcher? I have open windows of many apps, multiple windows of the same application, and I just want to switch between them. And without raising all windows of an application, which covers up my other windows.

Comment: is there a free version? all I want is one shortcut to switch per window not per app

Answer (score 13):

Along with the other suggested shortcuts, you could always use Exposé.

On a recent MacBook, or aluminium keyboard, the 'F3' key is dedicated to Exposé. If you don't have a keyboard with an Exposé key on it, you can use 'F9' and 'F10':

- <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd> to show *all* windows on the current space.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to show *all* windows belonging to the current application on the current space.

For even easier access, I use the four-finger upward swipe to activate Exposé.

Comment: It's actually not F3 key, it's a *fn* key located on top of the F3.

Comment: The issue with Exposé is that the order of the windows tiles/miniatures shown by Exposé changes. E.g. I have FireFox with six open windows. As soon as I switch from one of those windows to another, Exposé shows them next time in another unpredictable order and I loose the overview.

Comment: @t0r0X, Expose = Mission Control?

Answer (score 10):

On my Swedish Mac keyboard the <kbd>´</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> are on the same key. For the back-tick is a shifted forward-tick.

So, I can only use <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle the windows in one direction, and it doesn't work in all apps, like the terminal. Very annoying.

As Doug Harris pointed out [Witch](http://www.manytricks.com/witch/) is a really nice way of "solving" this problem for Windows to Mac switchers that have <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> the muscle memory.

Comment: For future visitors: to remap the keys, see also [Victor's comment](http://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac-os-x?noredirect=1#comment735095_45310) on the question. (But I guess that for you, Jörgen, after more than 3 years you're used to it now.)

Comment: Only $14 more to get your mac to be almost usable!  (Witch currently costs $14)

Comment: It's not just muscle memory, it often makes more sense to switch between individual windows and not applications: e.g. when you have multiple applications with multiple windows each, and want to keep one window of each on top and switch back and forth between the two.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, or if you're not sure, the one with the <kbd>~</kbd>.

This will cycle through all open windows for a single application.

Comment: Surround the text you want with <kbd> and </kbd>.

Comment: except in safari on a macbook plus with mountain lion...

Comment: @drevicko It works for me on that setup

Comment: @Diago interesting! Do you know if you did anything special to make it so? Mine is an out-of-the-box factory install just a few weeks old..

Comment: @drevicko Alt+` switches between **windows**. Ctrl+tab switches between **tabs**. Factory install on both my MacBook Pro and iMac. Just confirm which your trying to switch. I tend to ever only have one Safari window open but just tested again and it does work, actually it works in all application.

Comment: @Diago switching windows is what I'm after. I havn't found a way to do it with the keyboard ):  Apparently either I inadvertently did something to change the behaviour or perhaps my localisation (Australian) isn't set up properly?? As I recall, Alt-` works in some applications, but not most (my mac is in the office at the moment - I'll check which work when I go in tomorrow)

Comment: @Diago I've discovered that Alt+` switches between windows (in the same application) only when the windows aren't in full-screen mode. I've not found a way to use the keyboard to switch between full-screen windows.

Comment: @drevicko Interesting. I have a 27" iMac and at work a 24" external so hardly ever use fullscreen. Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 6):

Just a small clarification:

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

Switches between open windows for the same application, in OS "El Capitan" **this works only when the windows are not in fullscreen mode.** Maybe this is the reason because some guys reply saying that this shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I was having this issue until I took the window responsible out of fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

[Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/) is another commercial app that gives you a simple way to switch between application windows from the keyboard.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Optimal Layout.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> will cycle through open windows.

<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> will cycle through them in reverse.

Comment: This is incorrect.  It cycles through open windows of a given application.

Answer (score 2):

For switching through tabs, I prefer these shortcuts:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>{</kbd> to move left.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>}</kbd> to move right.

I find those keys more comfortable than the arrow keys.

Comment: there's also `ctrl+tab` and `ctrl+shift+tab` for even more uncomfortable ones. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mission Control. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ARROW UP</kbd> will activate Mission Control and it will show you all active windows separately. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ARROW DOWN</kbd> will show you all active windows of the current applications. So if you just want to switch between Chrome windows, this might be your solution!

Answer (score 1):

On Mountain Lion it became a (nicer IMO) <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. On a US keyboard, that is.

Comment: uh... on my US keyboard with mountain lion in chrome that switches which page element has focus...

Answer (score 1):

The best app for MS Windows like window switching is Contexts https://contexts.co/

Beautiful, perfect in every way and too cheap when considering how much everyday pain of OSX suboptimal window management it fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using HyperSwitch https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch/ these days as it not just supports window switching (as opposed to app switching) but also shows previews of windows in a way MS Windows started to do since Vista (or was it Windows 7?).

Answer (score 0):

If you want <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between all windows, you can try [Contexts](https://contexts.co/). I love it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Command-Tab Plus application which allows you to quickly switch between applications, and additionally between windows (using the ability of Mac OS cmd+tilde
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aL8CgMVptug

Comment: The problem of switching between applications and Windows applications faced by every Mac OS user, as I do not like the built-in Mac OS application switcher, then I have developed my decision. 

I tried a few solutions for switching between Windows and realized that I prefer to switch between applications. Maybe because I'm used to the MacOs, Mac OS x is slightly different ideology and so many people already switch between applications and not between windows

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what link you mean? Link to my website/site ?
[main suite](http://www.noteifyapp.com)

 [command tab plus link] (http://commandtab.noteifyapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

On a swedish keyboard it's `CMD + <` to switch between windows of a same app

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> Switches between open windows in an application.