# Mac OS X keyboard shortcut to switch between windows

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch between windows on mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac)

In Mac OS X, is it possible to switch between windows using a keyboard shortcut? More specifically I want to switch between windows within the same application. An example is I have multiple Firefox windows open. I want a keyboard shortcut to switch between the Firefox windows (or any other application's window). I'm aware of Command-Tab but it only switches between applications (and not windows).

I'm looking for the equivalent of Windows' Alt-Tab, which switches window instances and not application instances.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac

Answer (score 23):

Besides

- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> and
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>,

you might try using Exposé to switch windows. Hit <kbd>F10</kbd> (or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> if your <kbd>F3</kbd> has an Exposé icon on it), to activate single-application Exposé. Then you can use the arrow keys to pick a window (or point and click with the mouse). While in this single-application mode, <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> and its shifted version cycle through the active applications instead of the windows in an app (since all the windows of the app are already visible).

Comment: Please note that this will not work on most international keyboards. E.g. on german keyboard only this shortcut works:
`Shift`-`Command`-`´` which then effects to `Command`-`\``
This really sucks (the situation, not your answer!).

Comment: @Victor: You can change this shortcut in the keyboard system preferences; in German this is under Systemeinstellungen:Tastatur:Tastaturkurzbefehle:Tastatur & Texteingabe (System Preferences:Keyboard:Keyboard Shortcuts:Keyboard & Text Input)

Answer (score 7):

Command + `

(That's on the tildie key...)

Comment: Command-\` cycles through windows inside an application in one direction, Command-Shift-\` cycles the other direction.

Comment: @Chris what he meant is that shift+` = ~