# OS X keyboard shortcut to switch windows between same application

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch between windows on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac-os-x)

OS X Snow Leopard Server

For Google Chrome or Terminal, is there any keyshort to switch different Chrome windows within Chrome? Since <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> can only switch to different programs. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can configure the key combination in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts (tab) » Keyboard and Text Input (left list) » Move focus to next window in application (right list)*. This works globally for all applications.

[image: Screenshot]

For Terminal the Windows have a <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>*Number*</kbd> combination assigned (e.g. <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> for the first window).

[image: Screenshot]

You can display this shortcut in the window title in *Terminal » Preferences… » Settings » (select your active settings) » Window (tab)*. Check *Command key*.

Additionally, the shareware [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) provides several different Window switchers, like "*all windows of all applications*" etc.

Comment: Perfect answer  (thank you!!), but just to add, in "OS X El Capitan", you now need to change the shortcut which is simply called "Move focus to next window".

Comment: @Daniel, This **cycles** instead of alternate tab. What's the command to alternate?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but it appears to me that this keyboard shortcut works by default without any additional configuration.

Comment: @jpierson That's correct; I just included instructions how to change because it can be weird on some keyboard layouts. (Or used to be, it's been a while.)