# Can OS X's Command-Tab behavior of switching only between different apps and not including multiple instances of apps be changed?

Tags: windows, macos, finder, hotkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch between windows on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac-os-x)

In Windows, you switch between active windows with `Alt-Tab`.  This behavior includes all running apps and all instances of each app.  So if you have Calc open and 3 instances of Excel, there are 4 items to switch through.

In OS X, `Command-Tab` switches between apps but does not include multiple instances of each app - only the active instance.  So if you have Calc open and 3 instances of Excel, there are 2 items to switch through.  Command-` is used to switch between multiple instances of an app.

Can OS X's `Command-Tab` behavior be changed to work like Alt-Tab does in Windows?

Comment: @Daniel - My question wasn't how to switch between all apps and all instances of each app in OS X, it was asking how to modify Command-Tab's behavior so it does that.

Comment: To clarify, the difference between your question and the other is that you don't want to use a different tool or a workaround to achieve your goal? I decided to close this as a duplicate since it's essentially the same question. A positive answer to your question could be posted there as well.

Comment: @Daniel - Ideally I'd find out how to change the behavior of that sequence.  Finding an alternative is 2nd best.  If I use the other question, I am pretty much guaranteed to *not* get the answer to my main question.  Here's the solution - that question should be edited to include my additional detail.  I don't have enough points to do it.  Can you?  Also, can you change the closed message - it isn't an exact duplicate.  Thanks.